# Do planes in multi-dimensional spaces rarely intersect?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

Am I correct in saying two planes in 5-dimensional space will typically intersect in a point? Or will they not even intersect not at all?

Comment: It's similar to how it is in 3D, sometimes they intersect at a line, sometimes they overlap, sometimes they never interact.

Comment: @Prometheus, yes, in terms of possibilities, but while in 3D the typical intersection is a line, in 5D the typical intersection is the empty set...

Comment: A generic pair of hyperplanes of dimension $d_{0}$ and $d_{1}$ in $k^{d}$ has intersection a hyperplane of dimension $\max\left(d_{0}+d_{1}-d, 0\right)$. One way to see it is to use the fact that a generic $d$ by $\left(d-d_{0}\right)+\left(d-d_{1}\right)$ matrix with entries in $k$ has rank $\min\left(2d-d_{0}-d_{1}, d\right)$. The result generalizes in the obvious way to $n$-tuples of hyperplanes with natural $n$ other than $2$.

Comment: [This edit you made](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4319835/3) was a very bad move. It shifted the wording out from under existing answers, and also diminished the already meager context.  As a rule, a good post is going to be more than two sentences long.  If you haven't already, take a [look at this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/29335).

Answer (score 1):

The plane $\{(x,y,1,0,0)\}$ and the plane $\{(0,0,0,z,w)\}$ have empty intersection. This is typical, in the sense that in any reasonable parametrization ("moduli space") for such pairs of planes, the set of pairs with empty intersection is open and dense.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of it this way: in five dimensions, to specify a plane via equations of the form $ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3 + dx_4 + ex_5 = f$, you require three equations.

To specify the second plane is another three equations.

You now have six equations in five unknowns. What is the chance they have a solution? That is how likely you are to find a point of intersection of the two planes.